# Add image to Word document at specified position

Tags: vba, ms-word

My task is place image from external app at specified position in document. For example - i have Rich Text content control, and my image must appear on this content control. This is example of code:

```
Dim cc As ContentControl
Set cc = ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1)
ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture filename:=filename, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Anchor:=cc.Range
```

Inserted image located at the same height, but vertical is located on the left. According to documentation this behavior is correct, but i need to set it right above my `ContentControl` object. Is it possible to do it? Maybe i can calculate length of paragraph in pixel and set `Left` parameter in `Shapes.AddPicture` method?

Answer (score 3):

The `AddPicture` function returns a shape object which you can configure as desired:

```
Dim cc As ContentControl
Dim shp As shape
Set cc = ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1)

Set shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(filename:=filename, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Anchor:=cc.Range)
shp.Left = 20
shp.Top = -100
```

You can also set the `RelativeHorizontalPosition` and `RelativeVerticalPosition` properties of the shape object to specify how the left and top values are to be interpreted.