# Problem inserting Image at a specific position

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been using the word VBA Shapes.AddPicture method (as in [Add image to Word document at specified position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39440746/155768829)) to insert a Png in a specific position of a document (near text previously found with Selection.Find.Execute...) and all has been working without problems for years, but now, without any change (nor in doc nor in code) the image has begun to go to top left corner and I couldn't find a reason...

Does someone know if something has change about that in last updates or what is happening?

I'm using properly updated 365 version and my code is:

```
Dim mySignatureShape As shape
Dim myImagePath as string

Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=" Text to find Here "
            
Selection.Collapse

myLeft = "-25"
myTop = "-49"

myImagePath = "Full Image Path Here"

Set mySignatureShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=myImagePath, LinkToFile:=False, _
                                                        SaveWithDocument:=True, 
                                                        Anchor:=Selection.Range, _
                                                        Width:="275", Height:="150", _
                                                        Left:=myLeft, Top:=myTop)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing anything to tell Word where to position the image in relation to the found text. As such, it could never have positioned the image 'near' that text unless the text was itself near the top of the page. Try:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim mySignatureShape As Shape
Dim myImagePath As String
Dim myLeft As Long, myTop As Long
myImagePath = "Full Image Path"
With Selection
  .Find.Execute FindText:="Text to find"
  .Collapse wdCollapseStart
  myLeft = -25 + .Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
  myTop = -49 + .Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
  Set mySignatureShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=myImagePath, LinkToFile:=False, _
    SaveWithDocument:=True, Anchor:=.Range, Width:=275, Height:=150, Left:=myLeft, Top:=myTop)
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Image is a signature, using to go at the end of documents and my code was working right until an Office update, a couple of weeks ago. I'm nearly sure something has change in function behaviour... 

Regarding the missing "Selection.information" part in my code, I supposed that there is a default setting for that in case you do not set (maybe they change this), but anyhow, I should recognize that your corrections do the trick and problem is now solved, at least in my current Office 365 install. 

Thanks a lot.
Thanks

Comment: Had you inserted the image as an InlikeShape after whatever text it relates to, you wouldn't have needed any of the vertical/horizontal positioning code. Regardless, the code you posted could not have done what you want in any Word version.

Comment: As I said, my code has been working correctly for years, making no sense whatsoever to lie here. 

Anyhow, I have finally found that problem wasn't in my template code itself (a global dotm), but in the new document created with it.

If the document is open in compatibility mode, my code work, but if it is in current version native mode (not compatibility mode) it don't. So now I'm sure something has change in Word... 

Thanks again for your interest.

Comment: Could someone check the result of Selection.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToTextBoundary) in different document locations? In my case that function always return 0, regardless of where selection/cursor is, while the other information constants (Horizontal... and ...To page) change without issues